# Importing a DataRowView Object to DataTable with ImportRow() Displays Empty Row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to transfer a selected item from my `DataGrid` to my `DataTable` that I will use to bind with another `DataGrid`. I import a row to the `DataTable` as follows:

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)firstDataGrid.SelectedItems[0]; //Picking the first one as an example
myDataTable.ImportRow(row.Row);
```

My `DataTable` has my other `DataGrid` binding to it as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:name="secondDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding myDataTable}"> //This is not the same data grid from above
```

I have a button that binds to a command that executes the first chunk of code as follows:

```
<ButtonCommand="{Binding DoFirstChunkOfCodeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=firstDataGrid}"></Button>
```

However, when I test it out, it ends up adding only empty rows to my second `DataGrid`, I have confirmed that `row.Row` is NOT null by the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(row.Row["SomeColumn"].ToString());
```

Which ended up opening a message box containing the correct value. So, why then is an empty row being added to my dataGrid when the row is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have to add the columns to my `DataTable` first before importing rows as follows:

```
DataColumn column;

//Repeat this chunk for each column, changing DataType and ColumnName as neccessary
column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
column.ColumnName = "col1";
myDataTable.Columns.Add(column);
```

This makes the ImportRow() method function as expected to.